# What can be defined as a Regular Set

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm currently studying compilers and am having some issues with understanding regular sets. For example, lets say I had a set of binary strings, (0, 1). Would all integers that are even and positive be considered part of a regular set? Lets say I have that same set, but instead of being even, they are divisible by 5, would it still be a regular set?

I've been looking at [this helpful guide](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/texts/theory/automata/reg-sets.pdf) I found online, but I'm still confused about what can be defined as a regular set.

Answer (score 2):

A regular set is the same thing as a regular language. You haven't explained how to encode integers, but suppose you encode an integer in binary notation, MSB first; so each zero is represented as $0$, and all other numbers start with $1$. The set of even positive integers is the represented by the regular expression $1(0+1)^*0$ (why?), and so is regular. The set of non-negative integers divisible by $5$ is also regular, since there is a DFA that accepts it; the minimal DFA has $5$ states corresponding to the value of the current prefix modulo $5$, which is updated in the obvious way. I'll let you figure out the details.